# Using Avro to java plugin in gradle kotlin dsl

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I've a java project that is built using gradle kotlin dsl.

Now I want to use gradle-avro-plugin like this https://github.com/davidmc24/gradle-avro-plugin#alternate-usage

In kotlin dsl I have written the same logic as below -

```
    plugins {
        java
        id( "com.github.davidmc24.gradle.plugin.avro") version "1.0.0"
    }

    dependencies {
    implementation ("org.apache.avro", "avro", "1.10.1")
    }

    val generateAvro = tasks.register<com.github.davidmc24.gradle.plugin.avro.GenerateAvroJavaTask>("generateAvro") {
    source("src/avro")
    this.setOutputDir(file("dest/avro"))
    }

    configure<org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile> {
       this.source = fileTree(generateAvro)
    }
```

The above code is returning below error when I run `grade compileJava`-

```
   > * What went wrong:
```

> Extension of type 'JavaCompile' does not exist. Currently registered extension types: [ExtraPropertiesExtension, DefaultArtifactPublicationSet, SourceSetContainer, ReportingExtension, JavaPluginExtension, JavaInstallationRegistry, JavaToolchainService, DistributionContainer, JavaApplication, DefaultAvroExtension]

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues, what worked for me was:

```kotlin
    plugins {
        id("com.github.davidmc24.gradle.plugin.avro") version "1.2.0"
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation("org.apache.avro:avro:1.10.1")
    }

    tasks.withType<com.github.davidmc24.gradle.plugin.avro.GenerateAvroJavaTask> {
            setOutputDir(file("src/dest/dir/"))
    }
```

The important thing is I did not registered a new task, just specified a new destination directory for each task with the type `GenerateAvroJavaTask`